# How do I get more flavor in the interior of a brisket?

Tags: flavor, brisket

My brisket doesn't have a lot of flavor on the inside. The outside is full of flavor but when getting to the inside it doesn't have much flavor to wow my guests. How do I get more flavor to the interior?

I'm cooking it in the oven, by the way. BBQ is not my thing.

Comment: Hello and welcome - we'll be much better able to help if you can add more details on your recipe/method. Simply knowing that it's cooked in the oven isn't enough to indicate where things might be going wrong.

Comment: Hello & welcome, too. One hint for new users: asking for "the best way" is going to raise a few eyebrows here as the question might be considered too broad. It's always a good idea to a) say what you did & didn't like then b) ask for specific ideas how to improve your method. I suggested an edit (also for better readability), but you can change it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Part of the issue could be quality of the meat you are buying. Interior should taste like beef.

Comment: Also, when you eat it, make sure you get some of the outside in every bite!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to make the interior smaller, which could be accomplished in several ways, such as slicing the brisket ahead of time or cutting it in half vertically. This would give you a larger surface area to season, decreasing the amount of unflavored meat and shortening cooking time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't typically cook brisket, but when I cook other large slabs of meat for london broil, I'll tenderize it by stabbing it repeatedly with a fork (evenly over the whole surface, flip, then do it again on the other side), drop it into a zip-top bag, then coat it liberally with worcestershire sauce.  I'll then add a good bit of soy sauce to the bag, compress out the air, and let it sit for somewhere between an hour and a day (depending on how far in advance I have to prep it).

Something similar should work for you, although you're likely going for a low and slow cook, while I stick mine under the broiler for a few minutes.

Your other option is just to serve it with a good sauce ... or catch the drippings so that you can slice the meat and let it soak in the juices before you serve your guests.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try making it the day ahead.

My usual brisket recipe braises in a beer, onion, and chili sauce; but I make it the day before, and slice it thin; and keep the sauce and sliced brisket separately in the fridge.

Then, the next day, I layer the slices in a baking dish, skim the fat off the sauce, pour it over and reheat.

Because the slices reheat in the sauce, it has plenty of flavour.